# I Cant ran mysql command in terminal in Ubuntu Saucy Salamander

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

Hi attached is the image showing MySQL Server is currently running and succesfully installed in Ubuntu 13.10, only problem is I cannot communicate with it via terminal so I can't create databases using terminal.

It say's mysql is not currently installed, so what am i missing?

below is that url that I used to install it.
https://serverfault.com/questions/516190/how-to-install-mysql-5-6-on-debian-7-wheezy

[image]

Comment: Maybe your mysql client is not in the path? If you are inside of the folder, where your mysql client is, try ./mysql -u root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the current directory is not in your `PATH`, so it's not searched when you execute commands.

You can do any of the following:

- Add `/usr/local/mysql/bin` to your path (probably best option)
- From inside that directory, run `./mysql` rather than `mysql`
- Type `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql` instead of `mysql`
- Create an alias
- ...